# C++ look-up-table for modbus slave

Tags: c++, multithreading, modbus

I have C firmware that implements a modbus slave. Once my RTU command (say func 03 "register read") is received I simply go to a LUT and fetch the data I need to return. My data structs are global. My array looks something like this:

```
int* modbusLUT[]={
                   &motorControl_t.counter.degrees,
                   &motorControl_t.counter.dir,
                   &glueControl_t.nozzle.temp,
                   &paintControl_t.hopper.level,
...
};
```

and I build the modbus reply something like this:

```
temp = *modbusLUT[startAddr+j];
...
```

This **single thread** code works great and rather efficient.

I'm now writing separate C++ "system manger" code that is essential headless and it too must act like a modbus slave. I intend to wrap the mechanics of the system into three classes. Each class is created on the heap and starts it's **own thread** awaiting events from main(). Something like this:

```
m_ptrMotorMachine = new CMotorMachine();
m_ptrGlueMachine  = new CGlueMachine();
m_ptrPaintMachine = new CPaintMachine();
...
m_ptrGlueMachine->m_pThread->PostThreadMesageA(SW_PART_IN_PLACE,0,0);
```

I need parameters (member variable) from all three classes available so that my modbus handler can access and read/write them...  Ideally like the C array above.

So, how can I safely do something like above in C++? Need locks? Pseudo code something like this:

```
class CModBusSlave{
void initLUT()
   {
    int* modbusLUT[]={
                     &m_ptrMotorMachine->velocity,
                     &m_ptrMotorMachine->accel,
                     &m_ptrGlueMachine->psi,
                     &m_ptrPaintMachine->stroke,
                     ...
                     };
   };       
};
```

Any thoughts or alternative designs is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend not using `PostThreadMesageA` and instead using C++ standard library support for multiprocessing. You'll appreciate it if you ever decide you need to run your PC code under Linux. Visual C++ support for these is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

if i had understood your problem, you don't have to implement some sort of thread safe mechanism, whith multithread you have to worry when the resources are contended, with the modbus protocol you have separate adresses and register adresses and the comunication mechanism is answer/reply based so the master ask to do something and only the interested slave do that thing on a note adress.
You can use your thread to do handle the information and use the manager to start the proper thread. there is no concurrency if you strictly respect the standard protocol soyou don't have to worry to much.
Maybe we can think on something when you have defined what your threads will do exactly. 
if you don't have any particular problem i think your single thread versione would be nice enough!

Comment: I'm sorry, should have been clearer... The single threaded C code is firmware running in a micro-controller on a PCB and is simply an example of my implementation.  The mutlithreaded C++ code will be running on a PC and talking modbus to an external HMI.  This C++ code design is what is giving me trouble.

Comment: i don't think to have understood your problem at all, but if you are worried about the data structure to use to store your data like you did in your firmware you can use the standard c++ data structure like vectors. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/. if you have any other concern please give me details about and i try to figure out

Comment: I'm doing a poor job of explaining the issue.  It's not about the data structures, it's about using C++ to create a similar LUT than I did in C when I was using global structures. Perhaps I can do just the same and don't even realize it?  I have to find a better way to explain.

Comment: c++ support c syntax so if your c code respect the standard syntax you can use the same method, i think you can just do the same